# Finding a count of children entities using JPA CRUD Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have been using JPA CRUD repository default methods such as find, findAll, delete, etc. for all my database operations.

Right now I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Parent parent;  
}
```

Is there a way for me to create a new method in ParentRepository that would let me retrieve a count of all the Children of a parent based on the parent's ID?

So inside my ParentRepository, can I create a method that looks something like this:

```
int findAllChildrenCount(Long parentID);
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

```
public interface ParentRepo extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {

    Long countByChildren_Parent(Parent parent);

    @Query("select count(c) from Parent p join p.children c where p = ?1")
    Long countChildrenByParent(Parent parent);

    Long countByChildren_ParentId(Long id);

    @Query("select count(c) from Parent p join p.children c where p.id = ?1")
    Long countChildrenByParentId(Long id);
}

public interface ChildRepo extends JpaRepository<Child, Long> {

    Long countByParent(Parent parent);

    @Query("select count(c) from Child c where c.parent = ?1")
    Long countChildrenByParent(Parent parent);

    Long countByParentId(Long id);

    @Query("select count(c) from Child c where c.parent.id = ?1")
    Long countChildrenByParentId(Long id);
}
```

Comment: Please confirm if the `COUNT` is working in the @Query. I tried it didn't work. When I use the `SIZE` it worked as per @xyz 's answer below.

Answer (score 8):

```
@Query("select size(u.children) from Parent u where u.id=:parentID")
int findAllChildrenCount(@Param("parentID")Long parentID);
```

Comment: I tried `COUNT` and didn't work. The `SIZE` is working. Thanks